# DataTables two_button pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I'm trying to figure out why my DataTables table has only a couple squares for the next and previous navigation buttons like shown here in this image.

[image]

The 2 gray squares after the table information are the buttons that are used for navigation.

I don't know why they would just be showing up as a couple of squares, instead of looking like actual buttons with the 'Next' and 'Previous' text on them like when you use full_numbers pagination with DataTables.

I don't think there is anything in the CSS or javascript that applies to these buttons that would be overwriting their look.

my sDom looks like `"sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>'`.

The full table declaration looks like

```
$('#DataTable').dataTable({
        "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sPaginationType": "two_button",
        "sAjaxSource": AjaxDataSource.URL,
        "aoColumns": [{ "sTitle": "ID" }, 
            { "sTitle": "Account Number" }, 
            { "sTitle": "Account Type" }],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "iCookieDuration": 15
    }).fnSetFilteringDelay(1500);
```

Comment: have you copied the images directory? is should be on the same directory where the css directory is.

Comment: The jQueryUI Images directory?

Comment: don't know how you have installed `DtaTables`. Check the `media` directory in the `DtaTables` package.

Comment: @bansi You were absolutely right about my images directory. The jquery ui images folder was in a different location than it was supposed to be, so it could not find the images. I never knew that jqueryui used a single image and then applied offsets to create it's controls like it does.

Comment: @bansi we ended up scrapping datatables anyway in favor of ASP.NET gridview.